# C++ string function error and Print

Tags: c++, arrays, string, printing

So I am working on this project that ask for the user to input practically as many customers into the system as needed. They should input customer name, motion Picture, quanity of each item and cost. Later it should provide sum, average and etc. (average, and etc I haven't implemented just yet).

**UPDATE:**

I have fixed my string but I think something is wrong with my print array. Not exactly sure how to get my name into a string so that I can keep Alyssa and Dave There error is just a bunch of numbers that just keep going:

PROGRAM RUNNING

```
Welcome to our storing system for your account information
If you wish to begin inputting information, Please enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No
1
Enter customer's first name:
Alyssa
To choose which Motion Picture that you purchased a DVD under:
Enter 1 for Paramount. Enter 2 for Twentieth Century Fox.
Enter 3 for Warner and 4 for WaterFront

Input the data in the following format.
Motion Picture Number <space> Amount of motion pictures purchased <space>  Cost of movies
Enter -1 <space> 0 <space> 0 <space> to end

1 2 20
Enter Motion Picture <space> Amount purchased <space> Cost of movies
2 33 201
Enter Motion Picture <space> Amount purchased <space> Cost of movies
-1 0 0
Still have more employees? Enter 1 to add them or 2 to end

1
Enter customer's first name:
Dave
To choose which Motion Picture that you purchased a DVD under:
Enter 1 for Paramount. Enter 2 for Twentieth Century Fox.
Enter 3 for Warner and 4 for WaterFront

Input the data in the following format.
Motion Picture Number <space> Amount of motion pictures purchased <space>  Cost of movies
Enter -1 <space> 0 <space> 0 <space> to end

1 4 20
Enter Motion Picture <space> Amount purchased <space> Cost of movies
-1 0 0
Still have more employees? Enter 1 to add them or 2 to end

2
```

ERROR

### Listed below is your totals within each Motion Picture Company

Customer Name      ParamountTwentieth Century Fox                 WarnerWaterFront
Dave 0 Dave 20 Dave 0 Dave 20 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave 0 Dave

The print I want:**

```
 Customer Name    Paramount   Twentieth Century Fox    Warner    WaterFront   Total

 Alyssa              2               4                   0            0        80
  Dave               3               0                   0            0       66.00
```

**

and so forth

MotionPicture.h

```
#ifndef MOTIONPICTURE_H
#define MOTIONPICTURE_H
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class motionPicture {


    public:

    motionPicture();
    void getData();
    static const int rows = 6;
    static const int columns = 100;
    void printArray();
    void getName();
    void setName();


    private:
            int company;
            double table[rows][columns];
            string name;

 };

 #endif
```

MotionPicture.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "motionPicture.h"
 #include <iomanip> //to use setw
 #include <cstring>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 motionPicture :: motionPicture() {

    //initalize the table
    for (int i =0; i < rows; i++){

            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++){

                    table[i][j] =0;
            }//end j for loop
    }//end i for loop

}//end constructor

void motionPicture :: setName(){

    cout<<"Enter customer's first name: " <<endl;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    getline(cin, name);
}//end setName

void motionPicture :: getName() {
    cout<< name;
//}//end getName

void motionPicture:: getData() {

    int system;
    int motion, quanity;
    double cost;

    cout <<"If you wish to begin inputting information, Please enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No"<<en$
    cin >> system;

    while (system !=2)
    {
    setName();
    //getName();

    cout <<"To choose which Motion Picture that you purchased a DVD under:"<<endl;
    cout <<"Enter 1 for Paramount. Enter 2 for Twentieth Century Fox."<<endl;
    cout <<"Enter 3 for Warner and 4 for WaterFront"<<endl<<endl;

    cout <<"Input the data in the following format."<<endl;
    cout <<"Motion Picture Number <space> Amount of motion pictures purchased <space>  Cost of m$
    cout <<"Enter -1 <space> 0 <space> 0 <space> to end"<<endl<<endl;

    cin >> motion >> quanity >> cost;

    while (motion != -1) {

                    table[motion-1][quanity-1] +=cost;

                    cout <<"Enter Motion Picture <space> Amount purchased <space> Cost of movies$
                    cin >> motion>> quanity >>cost;
            }//end cost while
    cout<<"Still have more employees? Enter 1 to add them or 2 to end" <<endl<<endl;
    cin >>system;
    }//end system while
}//end getData


void motionPicture :: printArray() {

cout <<"Listed below is your totals within each Motion Picture Company"<<endl;
cout <<"----------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

cout<<"Customer Name" <<setw(15) << "Paramount" <<setw(11) << "Twentieth Century Fox"
    << setw(23)<<"Warner" <<setw(8) <<"WaterFront" << setw(12)<<endl;
    for (int i= 0; i <rows; i++){
            //for(int j=0; j<100; j++){
            double total =0;
               // begin to print the table
               for (int j=0; j<columns; j++) {
                getData();
               cout table[i][j] << " ";
            //input total
            total += table[i][j];
            }//end j loop
    cout <<total<<"\n";
    }//end i loop
 }//end print
```

motionRun.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "motionPicture.h"


 using namespace std;

 int main () {

    cout << "Welcome to our storing system for your account information"
    <<endl;

    motionPicture objMotion;
    objMotion.getData();
    objMotion.printArray();

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: compiler already says what is wrong, also in which file, and which line

Comment: I know where the error is located. I am unfamiliar with the error's meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hidden issue in your class:

You have as private member:

```
       char static string1[];   // no space was reserved for this string !!
```

In the constructor you try to set the size by writing:

```
string1[20];   // this is only an expression returning the 20th element of string1.
```

But this won't work.  The string will not be reallocated, and when you'll store someting in it, ou'll have an error (with a little bit of luck a segmentation fault, but it could remain unnoticed as well).

I don't know if you really wan the string be `static`, which means shared by all the instances of your class...

The best you could do to solve your issue is to define your string  as a real c++ string:

```
   string string1;   // requires #include<string> of course
```

This will be a real dynamic string.  No longer need to worry for its size.  And your `getline()` will work as it is.

Comment: My comment above: So far I have changed my variable to a string string1[]; ... I have also realized from what I've heard is I still need my cin>>userInput; before I use getline and so forth. Still playing with it right now. Trying to figure out how to take the input and put it into my string1.

Comment: No [] shall be used if you define it as string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write

```
std::cin.getline(string1,20,'\n');
```

instead of

```
getline(string1,20,'\n');
```

within the function definition.

And you have to define static data member

```
char static string1[];
```

in a cpp module.

Also it is not clear what this line means in the constructor

```
string1[20];
```

Comment: that creates more errors: /tmp/ccTuXxxl.o: In function `motionPicture::getName()':
motionPicture.cpp:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `motionPicture::string1'
/tmp/ccTuXxxl.o: In function `motionPicture::printArray()':
motionPicture.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `motionPicture::string1'
/tmp/ccTuXxxl.o: In function `motionPicture::setName()':
motionPicture.cpp:(.text+0x3bc): undefined reference to `motionPicture::string1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Alyssa Cooke See my updated post. You have to define the static data member.

Comment: @AlyssaCooke Use `char motionPicture ::string1[20] ;` in cpp file.

Comment: So far I have changed my variable to a string string1[]; ... I have also realized from what I've heard is I still need my cin>>userInput; before I use getline and so forth. Still playing with it right now. Trying to figure out how to take the input and put it into my string1.